# Separate values from characters in R string

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation, tidyr

I have this problem. My dataset *a* contains one column badly formatted containing characters, letters and punctuation. I would like to separate column *Unit_Wrong* in two columns *num* and *text*.

Here is dataset a:

```
a <- data.frame(Measure = c(10000, 2000, 10000, 15000, 40000, 0), 
                Unit_Wrong = c("10L","25.5mL","30.5 mL","40OUNCES","3X", "NO_SIZE"), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

My expected outcome is *b*:

```
b <- data.frame(Measure = c(10000, 2000, 10000, 15000, 40000, 0), 
                Unit_Wrong = c("10L","25.5mL","30.5 mL","40OUNCES","3X", "NO_SIZE"), 
                text = c("L", "mL", "ml", "OUNCES", "X", "NO_SIZE"),
                num = c("10","25.5","30.5","40","3", ""),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I tried with this but it doesn't work:

```
attempt <- a %>% 
  mutate(text = gsub("[[:digit:]]","", Unit_Wrong)) %>%
  mutate(num = str_replace_all(Unit_Wrong, text, ""))
```

Can you help?

Comment: Error in data.frame(Measure = c(10, 2000, 10000, 15, 40), Unit_Wrong = c("10L",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 6

Comment: I forgot one value. Now it's correct

Comment: Try to master regular expressions. They are very important.

Comment: I need definetely to improve in string manipulation.

Comment: U can play and learn alot [here](http://regex101.com)

Answer (score 3):

```
    a %>%
mutate(text = stringr::str_extract(Unit_Wrong,"[A-z]+$")) %>%
mutate(num  = stringr::str_extract(Unit_Wrong,"(\\d\\.?)+") %>% as.numeric)
```

Output:

```
  Measure Unit_Wrong    text  num
1      10        10L       L   10
2    2000     25.5mL      mL 25.5
3   10000    30.5 mL      mL 30.5
4      15   40OUNCES  OUNCES   40
5      40         3X       X    3
6       0    NO_SIZE NO_SIZE <NA>
```

Note:

If you have special characters for unit like "µ" etc. You need to add those in
inside `[A-z]` like `[A-zµ]` and so on.

Comment: Not correct sorry. As you can see the final column contains 25 and 30 instead of 25.5  and 30.5.

Comment: ups ... fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an R base soluction using `gsub`

```
> text <- gsub("\\d*\\s*\\.*", "", a$Unit_Wrong)
> num <- as.numeric(gsub("\\s*[[A-Za-z]]*_*", "", a$Unit_Wrong))
> data.frame(a, text, num)
  Measure Unit_Wrong    text  num
1   10000        10L       L 10.0
2    2000     25.5mL      mL 25.5
3   10000    30.5 mL      mL 30.5
4   15000   40OUNCES  OUNCES 40.0
5   40000         3X       X  3.0
6       0    NO_SIZE NO_SIZE   NA
```